# JQuery table won't load., fails to load recource

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm making a table for my course, but the fancy table from datatables won't load, i'm just getting a boring old html table.

I've looked the code over in my book, it seems to be identical. Still im getting an error
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I don't know what is going wrong.
Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\bas_t\OneDrive\Code Educom\JQuery\JQuery\style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" />
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>

    <script>
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#theBeatles').DataTable();
      })   
    </script>
</head>
  
  <body>
    
     <table id="theBeatles" 
            class="display nowrap dataTable dtr-inline collapsed">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Instrument</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John Lennon</td>
                <td>john@thebeatles.co.uk</td>
                <td>Guitar</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- and so on with the other members --> 
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have invalid html and the file path for the CSS may not work

Do these things

1. Remove the self closing script tags and convert to `<script> your file </script>` - [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-elements-work)
2. You are trying to load a local css file - this may not work effectively, try serving it from a local server - may i suggest [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) OR Paste the value of the CSS file into a `<style>` tag

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to add a https: to the links, now it works.